# Does + sign need to be escaped ? Protractor + character not recognised in assertion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

i would like to assert that on focus an element has a certain naviID.
I have created a method that will identify the element focus attibute ' naviID'  and assert that it matches the String i give:

```
isFocused('document::first::0+0');
```

The problem  is that the assertion fails as the "+" character is not recognized by protractor.

When i try to assert that the focus is set on naviID containing no + sign ( e.g. 'document::first::0') error is not thrown and assert is successful.

Does + sign need to be escaped? How can i do that directly when i call the method?

Comment: Incase it's need to: Remember to use double slash: `0\\+0`. Or Javascript will peel it off: `"0+0" === "0\+0"`

Comment: @dev-null   I receive following error when using 0\\+0 Message:
 Expected [ 'document::first::0+0' ] to contain 'document::first::0\+0'  . From this i conclude that protractor sees it not escaped.. but still calling what is displayed as expected, assertion fails

Comment: I don't think protractor escapes `+` character as the value you are trying to assess is a string and whatever is in a string isn't escaped. You can try to print the values and see what is getting evaluated. Also can you update your question with the code or strings that the elements are returning? Thanks

Comment: @GirishSortur how can i print the values?

Comment: @user3188198 you can print values using `console.log()`. Also can you explain your question a little more? What value do you get and what are you trying to assert? If you could add the html element, it would be great. Thanks